# validating username while creating user in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here I am writing serializers for registering the users and trying to validate username with `validate_username` function but is not working.

> Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   string indices must be
>   integers Exception Location:  ...serializers.py in validate_username,
>   line 40

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer(required=False)
    email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=get_user_model().objects.all())])
    password1 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'profile']

    def validate_password1(self, password):
        validators.validate_password(password=password,user=get_user_model())

    def validate_password2(self, password):
        validators.validate_password(password=password,user=get_user_model())



    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] != data['password2']:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The two password fields didn't match.")
        return data

    def validate_username(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data['username']
        if len(username) < 6 and len(username) > 15:
            raise ValidationError('Username must be between 6 and 15 characters long')
        return username

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = get_user_model().objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name'],

        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password2'])
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()
        profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
        Profile.objects.create(
            user=user, address=profile_data['address'], contact=profile_data['contact']
        )

        return user
```

Comment: You don't have to validate `password2` if you validate `password1` and then validate if they are the same.

Comment: @Marek I was also thinking the same and so tried this but it always raise validation error of saying password didn't match so i validate both password1 and password2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are getting the actual value through argument(in your case, a string) when using [**`validate_<field_name>`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) method, not a dictionary. So the following code should fix it:

```
def validate_username(self, username):
    if len(username) < 6 or len(username) > 15:
        raise ValidationError('Username must be between 6 and 15 characters long')
    return username
```

Comment: tried but not checking the if condition though the error has gone now

Comment: @ruddra `if` condition should be `if len(username) < 6 or len(username) > 15`

Comment: not related but one question here above i am validating my passwords like this .It is working for now but is there any better approach for validating the password ?

Answer (score 0):

In the function validate_username, you are expecting validated_data as your argument. validate_ being custom "field level" validators,field value is the argument received. In general,

```
def validate_<field-name>(self, field_name):
    # Your code
```

In regard to having a better approach to validate passwords, regex expressions can be used.

For example,

> ^(?=.*\d).{4,8}$

This Password must be between 4 and 8 digits long and include at least one numeric digit.